# Regex to replace newlines with spaces, unless it's in same word as a given character

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string with multiple newlines, for example:

```
string = '\nsetting1: short string\nsetting2: much longer string\nwith a newline in it\nsetting3: short string\n'
```

I need a regex expression to use in the re.sub() function which will only match occurrences where the newline is not in the same 'word' as a colon. Such that the following substitution has the following output:

```
import re
re.sub(regex, ' ', string)

Out: '\nsetting1: short string\nsetting2: much longer string with a newline in it\nsetting3: short string '
```

No idea how I'd translate the 'if there is no colon anywhere in the word' part into regex, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Mikaelblomkvistsson, I believe Ben is referring to a "word" as any string on non-whitespace characters that is neither preceded nor followed by a non-whitespace character, `'string\nsetting2:'` being an example.

Comment: `\n` (a new line) is a whitespace character...

Comment: @Mikaelblomkvistsson I feel with the inverted commas around 'word' to convey I was using a loose definition of it, and the example input and output provided, that what I wanted was clear; thankfully 3 other people had the comprehension skills to answer such a ridiculous question

Answer (score 2):

You could do a regex replacement on `\n(?!\w*:)`, which excludes newlines followed by an optional word ending in colon.

```py
inp = '\nsetting1: short string\nsetting2: much longer string\nwith a newline in it\nsetting3: short string\n'
output = re.sub(r'\n(?!\w*:)', ' ', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
setting1: short string
setting2: much longer string with a newline in it
setting3: short string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start the match with the relevant match, which is here 1 or more word characters followed by a colon.

Then you can repeat matching 1 or more lines that start with 1 or more word characters that do not end with a colon.

Over that match, you can replace the newlines with a space.

```
^\w+:.*(?:\n\w+(?:[^\S\n].*)?)+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+:` Match 1+ word chars followed by `:`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:[^\S\n].*)?` Optionally match a space followed by the rest of the line
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times to match at least 2 lines in total
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6w3yAv/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/n8Ctk3)

Example

```
import re

string = "\nsetting1: short string\nsetting2: much longer string\nwith a newline in it\nsetting3: short string\n"
result = re.sub(r"(?m)^\w+:.*(?:\n\w+(?:[^\S\n].*)?)+$", lambda m: m.group().replace('\n', ' '), string)
print(result)
```

Output

```
setting1: short string
setting2: much longer string with a newline in it
setting3: short string
```